# How to create an array of objects using a loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

We're supposed to do this exercise for webdev class and I can't figure out how to solve it.

We have to create a 'person' object and fill it with random information using a method called `randomPerson()`. That part works fine so far.

```
let person = {
                fname: "",
                lname: "",
                city: "",
                street: "",
                hobbies: new Array(),
            }
```

After this, we're supposed to create another function that creates 10 of these random person objects and stores them in an array.

This is what I have so far:

```js
let person = {
  fname: "",
  lname: "",
  city: "",
  street: "",
  hobbies: new Array(),
};

personsArr = new Array();

function persons10() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // randomPerson() // makes it crash
    personsArr.fill(person)
  }
}
persons10()
console.log(personsArr)
```

When I try to run that, the page gets stuck loading and freezes.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what [`fill`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) does; your use of it makes no sense. Please also see [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](/q/35578478/4642212). Where is `randomPerson` defined?

Answer (score 2):

Fill is the wrong function to use for this use case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

The proper function to use in this case would be push: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

There are also a couple of mistakes in your code:

personsArr is never declared. It should be declared using either const or let. https://javascript.info/variables

```js
// since you didnt share the randomPerson() function, I created a dummy function
function randomPerson() {
  let person = {
                fname: "",
                lname: "",
                city: "",
                street: "",
                hobbies: new Array(),
  }


  return person;
}


let personsArr = new Array();

function persons10() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    personsArr.push(randomPerson());
  }
  
  console.log(personsArr);
  
}

persons10();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `randomPerson()` defined somewhere and it returns a person you need to assign it to I believe `person`. Then instead of `fill` you probably want `push` to add to the array not fill with the same person.

```js
function randomPerson() {
  return { // TODO randomize data
    fname: "",
    lname: "",
    city: "",
    street: `${Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1)+1} Street`,
    hobbies: new Array(),
  }
}

let personsArr = new Array();

function persons10() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let person = randomPerson()
    personsArr.push(person)
  }
}
persons10()
console.log(personsArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `personsArr` is never declared, you need to always have a variable initialized with a "let", "const" or "var" keyword. Same goes for the `person` variable which not only is not declared is not assigned anything either.

If you want to add a new element to an array you use the method `.push()` not `.fill()`.

Also if your program "crashes" as you said it, please include the Error message that you received in the console.

Comment: `let person` is the object at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses `Array#map` to create an array filled with random people.

`[...Array(n)]` is used to create an `Array` of length `n` to use as a basis for the map.

```js
const random = Math.random, trunc = Math.trunc
const createPerson = (fname, lname) => ({ fname, lname })
const firstNames = ['Sally', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Walter']
const lastNames = ['Smith', 'Bloggs', 'Black', 'White']
const createRandomPerson = () => 
  createPerson(firstNames[trunc(random() * firstNames.length)], 
               lastNames[trunc(random() * lastNames.length)])

const createNPeople = (n) => [...Array(n)].map(createRandomPerson)

console.log(createNPeople(10))
```